# Table centering (vertical)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to create an entry-page with four pictures as links to my other pages. But I want these pictures to be displayed in the middle (vertical and horizontal) of the monitor. I've tried quite a few things, but I cannot get it right. I can't even vertical-align the pictures on any way (for example bottom, as you'll see in the code).

Do you guys know a solution to this problem? Here my code:

HMTL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>B-Music: Piano</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="piano.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tablecontainer">
            <div id="tablerow">
                <div id="Column1">
                <div id="pianoleerkracht">
                    <a href="Prijs&Contact.html" title="Pianoleerkracht"> 
                        <img src="img/piano.jpg" alt="Pianoleerkracht"> 
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="jezelf">
                         <a href="Prijs&Contact.html" title="Jezelf"> 
                        <img src="img/piano.jpg" alt="Jezelf"> 
                         </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="column2">     
                <div id="mij">
                     <a href="Prijs&Contact.html" title="Mij"> 
                        <img src="img/piano.jpg" alt="Mij"> 
                     </a>
                </div>
                <div id="prijs&Contact">
                    <a href="Prijs&Contact.html" title="Prijs en Contact"> 
                        <img src="img/piano.jpg" alt="Prijs en Contact"> 
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: brown;
    height: 100%;
}

#tablecontainer{
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#tablerow{
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%
}

#column1{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#column2{
    display: table-cell;
}

img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the tablecontainer itself is being centered, however the content within the container has remained untouched by that css. Perhaps if you add the centering elements to the tablerow div it will correct the problem.

Here is what I would try:

```
#tablerow{
    display: table-row;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, no. This didn't do anythign at all actually.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need tables. css is enough:

```
#pianoleerkracht {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

i created a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tomaspolach/Q89f3/

Comment: This is quite like what I want to achieve. But I want the links to stand together as in this image: http://postimg.org/image/hfkrch00d/
The way you wanna do it, seems like quite tedious to achieve that. 
I'm also wondering why my way doesn't work. Do you have an explenation for that?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I found a solution to the problem. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      B-Music: Piano
    </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="piano.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Outer">
      <div id="Middle1">
        <div id="Inner1">
          <div id="pianoleerkracht">
            <a href="PrijsEnContact.html" title=
            "Pianoleerkracht"><img src="img/piano.jpg" alt=
            "Pianoleerkracht"></a>
          </div>
          <div id="jezelf">
            <a href="PrijsEnContact.html" title="Jezelf"><img src=
            "img/piano.jpg" alt="Jezelf"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Middle2">
        <div id="Inner2">
          <div id="mij">
            <a href="PrijsEnContact.html" title="Mij"><img src=
            "img/piano.jpg" alt="Mij"></a>
          </div>
          <div id="prijsEnContact">
            <a href="PrijsEnContact.html" title=
            "Prijs en Contact"><img src="img/piano.jpg" alt=
            "Prijs en Contact"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS of course:

```
body{
    background-color: brown;
    height: 100%;
}

#Tablecontainer{
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#tablerow{
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%
}

#column1{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
#column2{
    display: table-cell;
}

img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#Outer{
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#Middle1{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#Middle2{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#Inner1{
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
}

#inner2{
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Thank you guys for the inspiration!